# Why does FFT not have an effect on my smoothed signal?

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I'm playing with FFT at the moment and I try to get periods from noisy signals by recreating [this example](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/how-do-i-determine-if-a-discrete-signal-is-periodic-or-not). While experimenting, I've noticed that after smoothing a quite noisy signal, the result of `fft()` is actually the same signal again - which is what I don't understand.

Here is a full example which can be run in an IPython Notebook (You can [create a notebook here](https://tmp55.tmpnb.org/user/GEaBx8UfIc7m/tree) and run the code if you want).

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figsize = (16,8)
n = 500
ls = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, n)

x_target = np.sin(12*ls) + np.sin(52*ls)

x = np.sin(12*ls) + np.sin(52*ls) + np.random.rand(n) * 3.5
x = x - np.mean(x)

x_smooth = pd.rolling_mean(pd.DataFrame(x), 14).replace(np.nan, 0.0).as_matrix()
x_smooth = x_smooth - np.mean(x_smooth)

x_smooth = np.roll(x_smooth, -7)

# Getting shwifty and showing what we've got
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.scatter(ls, x, s=3, c=[1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0])
plt.plot(ls, x_target, color=[1.0,0.0,0.0, 0.3])
plt.plot(ls, x_smooth)

plt.legend(["Target", "Smooth", "Noisy Data"])

# Target
x_fft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x_target))
pd.DataFrame(x_fft).plot(figsize=figsize)

# Looks like it should
x_fft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))
pd.DataFrame(x_fft).plot(figsize=figsize)

# Plots the same signal?
x_fft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x_smooth))
pd.DataFrame(x_fft).plot(figsize=figsize)
```

Below you find the resulting plots of this script.

#### Noisy data with smoothed signal:

[image]

#### FFT of the target function

[image]

#### FFT of the noisy data

[image]

#### FFT of the smoothed data

[image]

I don't really get why this is the case here. Can somebody explain this to me or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: These two signals do not look identical (but it does look like the noisy and the smoothed plots are swapped over).  With the noisy plot, you should see more high frequency content, particularly as the noise is so large.  After filtering, the noise level will reduce in the higher frequency bands.

Comment: @Dave You can [create a notebook here](https://tmp55.tmpnb.org/user/GEaBx8UfIc7m/tree) and run my code if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical difference is between:

```
 x_fft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x_smooth))
```

and

```
 x_fft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x_smooth.flatten()))
```

because it seems that `x_smooth` has gotten itself all 2-dimensional somewhere along the way.   Its shape is (500,1) and because `np.fft.fft` works by default along `axis=-1` (i.e. the highest dimension) it is taking the 500 separate FFTs of 500 different 1-sample signals. (Unsuprisingly enough, that returns only the DC component for each, so put them all together and you end up with the same signal you started with.)

The FFT from the smoothed signal really looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Omg you're right. I didn't see this! I already thought if I'm stupid or what ... thanks man .. I thought I was going crazy right there ..